# Degree of a map from $ T^2 \rightarrow T^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Given a map $f:T^2 \rightarrow T^2$, the degree of $f$ is given by the induced homomorphism $f^*:H_2(T^2) \rightarrow H_2(T^2)$.

If I know the induced homomorphism $f^{**}:H_1(T^2) \rightarrow H_1(T^2)$ is $f(x+y) = mx + ny$ (since $H_1(T^2) = \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}$) can I calculate the degree of the map?

Comment: Look at the determinant of the matrix defining $f^{**}$.

Comment: @studiosus Are you suggesting passing to cohomology and the cup product or is this simpler than that?

Comment: It is simpler than that: Use the fact that every endomorphism of the torus is homotopic to an affine one, i.e., the one which lifts to an affine map of $R^2$.

Comment: This question is related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/776839/4583

Comment: @studiosus sorry, I am having some difficulty understanding, my knowledge is fairly limited. Are you saying if $f:S^1 \times S^1 \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$ is $(x,y) \mapsto (nx + my, kx + ly)$ then $deg(f) = nl -km$?

Comment: @user152723: Exactly! In addition, every continuous map is homotopic to the one you wrote.

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand the comments into a complete answer:

1. $T^2$ is a $K(\mathbb Z^2,1)$, so basepoint-preserving homotopy classes of maps $T^2\to T^2$ are in bijective correspondence with fundamental group homomorphisms $\mathbb Z^2\to \mathbb Z^2$.
2. Since $\mathbb Z^2$ is abelian, the homotopy classes of maps are in bijective correspondence with homomorphisms $H_1(T^2)\to H_1(T^2)$.
3. If $f_*:H_1(T^2)\to H_1(T^2)$ is defined by $f_*(v)=Av$, with respect to some basis of $H_1(T^2)$, and with $A$ a $2\times 2$ integer matrix, then we may as well let $f$ be $f([x])=[Ax]$, where $x\in\mathbb R^2$ is a point in the universal cover, and where $[x]$ denotes the corresponding image in $T^2$.  This $f$ induces the same map on $H^1$, so it must be homotopic to whatever the original $f$ was.
4. If $A$ is singular, then the degree is $0$.  Otherwise, $\lvert \det A\rvert $ gives $\lvert f^{-1}(x_0)\rvert$, and the sign of $\det A$ gives the local degree ($\pm 1$), so $\det A$ is the degree.

Comment: This begs the question: Why is $|\det A| = |f^{-1}(x_0)|$? (I assume $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^2$.)

Comment: @fish_monster $x_0\in T^2$. Here's the picture to have in mind: $T^2$ is represented by the integer lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$ in the sense that the unit square is its fundamental domain, and the $A$ matrix is mapping this fundamental domain to a parallelogram with integer coordinates, where $\lvert \det A\rvert$ is the area of this parallelogram. The point $x_0$ is represented by a shifted copy of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, and $\lvert f^{-1}(x_0)\rvert$ is the number of points of this shifted lattice inside the parallelogram (but only include one of each pair of parallel sides).

Comment: If you want, this is a special case of Pick's theorem, that to get the area of the parallelogram you just have to count lattice points. But we can also figure this out by either doing shear transformations of the parallelogram (which preserve the area).